# Why do PHP versions prior to 8.0 reject the namespace "Random\Namespace" as invalid syntax?

Tags: php, namespaces

```
<?php
namespace Random\Namespace;
```

When I run this code on 3v4l.org (https://3v4l.org/kk0bD) it works fine on PHP 8.0.0+ but on PHP >= 5.4.0 and PHP < 8.0.0 I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Namespace' (T_NAMESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

I don't understand. namespaces have been around in PHP since PHP 5.3.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like the word `Namespace` is reserved.

Comment: I've just played with this in PHP 5.6 ... It's because Namespace is a keyword.
If you try `namespace Random\SomethingElse` it works. I assume, "they" considered it to be a bug and fixed it in PHP 8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Until PHP 8.0, every component in a namespace was considered as a distinct name, and each part could not use any of the [list of reserved keywords](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

In this case, the namespace `Random\Namespace` contains the reserved name "Namespace" as one of its components, so is rejected by the parser.

In PHP 8.0, [a change to the parser was introduced](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/namespaced_names_as_token) where the entire namespace name is treated as a single token (as part of a general trend to making keywords reserved in as few contexts as possible). So for PHP 8.x, the name is parsed in one go as "Random\Namespace", which is not reserved.

The linked proposal notes that the keyword `namespace` is still reserved at the *start* of namespace names, because it would cause ambiguity in some contexts, so `namespace Namespace\Random;` is still an error.